# Why do I get "TypeError: Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not a function"

Tags: node.js, angular, ng2-file-upload

I'm working on File Upload with Angular2 and Node.js with ng2-File-Upload
but while running my project i got an error related to Reflect.getOwnMetadata
here is the error shown :

[image]

and here is my systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
      /** Path for ng2-file-upload */
      'ng2-file-upload' : 'npm:ng2-file-upload' 
      /** Path for ng2-file-upload */
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './transpiled-js/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      /** Configuration for ng2-file-upload */
      'ng2-file-upload' : { 
        main: './ng2-file-upload.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
      /** Configuration for ng2-file-upload */
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: post the code related to file upload.

Answer (score 0):

This is the scenario when I faced the exact same issue:

I had two TypeScript files with the same name (say, `FileUploadService.ts`) residing in two different locations. One was for handling server logic (residing in a `server` directory), and the other in a `public` directory for file upload through an Angular service.

> The problem was that I was importing the wrong service in a location where the `ng2-file-upload` package was used, which in turn depends on Angular modules - which were never being imported.

This meant that the file where `Reflect.getOwnMetadata` is defined somewhere was unavailable during the Typescript compilation.

Please make sure you reference the correct file in the correct location which might be the case for you too.